# Is there a way to loop through all assigned variables in a JS file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Say there is a vars.js:
`let a = "a"  let b = "bbb"  let cca = "vsa"`

Say there are 1000 of these variables.
Is there a way to loop through them using only JS or node.js ?

Thank you in advance.

I was trying to push them all to a array so that I can loop through them.

Comment: Why don't you just create the array/object straight away instead of defining thousands of variables? This can lead to memory issues if you define many variables.

Comment: The question is why would you even need to define so many variables? Use either an object or an array.

Comment: Yes, use an object instead. This is _not_ what variables are for.

Comment: So if you are using a JavaScript framework like React.js it's possible using module.

so in your first file you will have something like this, let's call it `variables.js`

```js
export let a = "a",
  b = "bbb",
  cca = "vsa";
```

and in another file where you wish to spread them you can import them all like this, and get all their values in an array. 

```js
import * as all from "src/variables";

const myArr = all;

console.log({ myArr: Object.values(myArr) });
```

Comment: _"I was trying to push them all to a array so that I can loop through them."_ But to do that you would have to loop over them first.